# Indoor cyclist keeps popping out of clips

Tags: pedals, spd, indoor

I bought a pair of Shimano indoor cycling shoes with two hole cleats to wear during my spin classes.  Unfortunately, during my classes, I snap out of the clips.  I know part of it must be my form but I think another part is that the clip isn't held in like mountain bike shoes are.  Is there a way to buy an attachment to make mine more sturdy. I know there must be something, but I can't seem to find it!

Comment: Note that the cleats can adjusted slightly by loosening the screws and twisting clockwise or counterclockwise.  This will allow you to make the "preferred" orientation of your foot on the pedal a little more toe-inward or toe-outward as need be (within the limits of having your heel bump the crank arm).  When you're pedaling "in form" you want your feet to be able to twist slightly either direction without bumping into the limits of the cleats.

Answer (score 8):

On Shimano SPD pedals, you can sometimes adjust the tension for how tightly they clip in (likely via a hex bolt). If the tension is too low, your feet will be too easy to pop out, whereas if its too high, you won't easily be able to get out (which isn't a problem on an indoor cycling setup). Try playing with this setting to see if you stay clipped in (turning the bolt clockwise should increase the tension).

Also, there are two types of cleats  available -- single release (Shimano SH-51) which only release by turning your heel out and multi-release (Shimano SH-56) which release by turning in any direction. It shouldn't matter which one you use for indoor cycling (SH-56 is probably preferable for most people) but SH-51 might be an option if you're having trouble with SH-56.

If you can't get the tension to adjust and swapping the cleats doesn't work (if you're using SH-56), normally indoor cycling bikes have toe clips available as well. You may want to use those. And work on your form.

Comment: Depending on your bike (whether your fit hits something first) you can also release SH-51 by turning your heel *in*. SH-56 adds the ability to pull upwards.

Comment: "won't easily be able to get out (which isn't a problem on an indoor cycling setup)." That depends on _how_ difficult it is to get out. Outdoors, you fall over if you stop but you can pee while on the bike; indoors, you don't fall over if you stop but you need to get off to pee. ;-)

Comment: One thing to remember when adjusting the tension is that (assuming you are using double-sided pedals), you should adjust both sides by the same amount at the same time. Otherwise, you're liable to end up with a pedal that is sometimes easy and sometimes hard to get out of.

Comment: You can turn in if your feet are small enough (I'd guess it works for people who are under maybe US 8 or 9 mens; I have heel strike at US 13), but I don't think its a good practice to encourage. As for stopping to pee, I hope people have better timing that that isn't a problem. And that is a good point with the double sided pedals, but I think spin classes are normally one sided (but I rarely use bikes at the gym).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to adjusting the spring tension, you may want to
confirm that you have the [SM-SH51](https://ridecanada.shimano.com/products/sm-sh51) cleats
and not the [SM-SH56](https://ride.shimano.com/products/sm-sh56)  cleats.

As Chris H points out in a comment, SM-SH51 is unclipped by twisting either out *or in*. (Notice that if the cleats unclipped by twisting just out they would need to be identified as "right" and "left".)

SM-SH56 additionally enables unclipping by [lifting and twisting your heel](https://ride.shimano.com/products/sm-sh56), which may be the motion that makes you inadvertently unclip.

[image: Aside from color, the SH-51 looks strikingly similar to the SH-56]

[image](https://www.competitivecyclist.com/shimano-spd-cleat-sets)
[source](https://www.competitivecyclist.com/shimano-spd-cleat-sets-shi0341)

##### "Cleats Included"

Notice that the cleats that you get
[by default](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/components/mtb/category/pedal.html)
with SPD pedals from Shimano are the
[SM-SH51](https://ride.shimano.com/products/sm-sh51)
(rather than the multi-release
[SM-SH56](https://ride.shimano.com/products/sm-sh56)).

Answer (score 2):

@Batman has already explained [how to adjust SPD release tension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/40446/8273) (+1 to him).

Pedalling smoother will also help.

Try to use you ankles more, so that you are trying to drive the pedals through all 360°.

And try to pedal straight, as in keep your feet pointed directly forward all the time. Keeping your knees straight can help with this, and focussing on a distant point can help too.

As with any technique training (whether it's cycling, swimming, squash, tennis, skiing, whatever) you'll need to focus just on technique for a while, and ignore speed and power. When you think you've improved the technique, test it by applying more power.

Because the new technique uses different muscles, build it up carefully to avoid soreness.

Answer (score 1):

Devil's advocate here, but why not try using flat pedals on your spin classes?  It would teach you correct technique by spinning in "circles".

But anyway, the previous answers have hit it right on the head, it is either you are using a multi-release cleat or the tension in the pedals are too low or that you are "jerky" in your pedalling movements.  remember, pedal in circles and make it smoother :)

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @nino :-)

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that "pedalling in circles" means applying the same amount of power all the way through the pedal's rotation (e.g., pushing down when it's at the front and pulling up while it's at the back). You can't learn to do that with flat pedals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've never heard of anyone applying the same force on down- and upstroke, including pros. About the best you can do is not apply force on the upstroke by lifting your foot, but you can do it with or without clipless pedals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Being able to pedal in circles with flats is quite possible.  Does require you to articulate your ankle a little more.  Toes down to push it back at the bottom of the rotation, heals down at the top to push it forward at the top.  Yes, still a little dead zone at the horizontal but still near full circle and compensated by power on the other side

Answer (score -2):

Add more resistance. Period. You’re probably out spinning your current cadence. Whenever it happens to me, I know I need more resistance. Means you’re getting stronger. :)

Comment: Why is this more likely than the cleat being too loose?  Personally I find I'm more likely to yank my foot out of the pedal if I'm really stomping a big gear; this feels completely backward to me.  What kind of mechanism would cause this?

Comment: Also, if you’re spinning out it’s probably that you’re too slow, not that the cadence is too much

Comment: I presume you're suggesting to add more resistance to the spin-bike, rather than the pedal-release mechanism?  This would be a valid answer, because it will force the rider to pedal slower and more "deliberately" potentially letting the rider transfer weight to the forward pedal.   A high cadence could definitely contribute.